# Trying to use Expect to receive long login sequence from multiple telnet spawn

Tags: expect

In Expect, if I have started multiple spawned telnet sessions to network nodes, and then send user/pw in a loop to all of them that takes ~10 sec to complete (it's a local CLI that is very slow to start), shouldn't they be finished more or less at the same time if I'm doing the "expect"- command in a separate loop after the "send"- loop?

First loop

```
while {[gets $nodelist node] != -1} {
    spawn telnet $node
    expect "login:" {send "user"}
    expect "word:" {send "pw"}
    lappend spawnlist $spawn_id
}
```

and in next loop

```
for {set i 0} {$i < $nbrOfSpawns} {incr i 1} {
    set spawn_id [lindex $spawnlist $i]
    expect "$prompt"
}
```

This doesn't work for me as I hoped, the CLI initiation doesn't start until each spawn_id is active in the second loop so I still have to wait for each of them.
Am I missing something or is this how it works?

regards Olle

Comment: what is `$prompt` ?

Comment: And shouldn't `$nbrOfSpawns` be `llength $spawnlist` ?

Comment: The $prompt is just the expected prompt from the nodes when it's done loading the CLI.

Comment: $nbrOf Spawns is exactly that, llength $spawnlist, just tried to shorten the text a bit, sorry!

Comment: You probably need to also copy your second loop code for the expect/send login, and the expect/send password parts, too.

Comment: Both loops are pasted in the text above I think, the first loop sending user and password, the second loop waitng for the prompt from the network nodes. Or did you mean something else?